# Getting wrong page access_token using PHP SDK 3.1.1?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, access-token

I'm trying to check whether the page has a tab installed. I use

```
$tabs = $facebook->api("id_page/tabs?access_token=".$page_access_token);
```

but I get a "(#210) Subject must be a page." error. My app has email and manage_pages permissions and I get the page access token using this call

```
$page = $facebook->api("/id_page?fields=access_token&access_token=".$access_token);
```

The access token which I get is something like

```
id_app|opaque_string-uid|id_page|opaque_string
```

When I try to simulate it in Graph API explorer (it has the same permissions), I get a long string which doesn't contain IDs in it as an access token

Could you pls tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make request via GET HTTP METHOD not POST